# create a json from two lists to make a stacked bar chart in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, dictionary, plotly

create a json from two lists to make a stacked bar chart in Javascript

```
list1 = ['2019-03-05', '2019-02-20', '2019-02-20', '2019-02-19', '2019-02-18', '2019-02-16', '2019-02-13', '2019-02-12', '2019-02-12', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-08', '2019-02-07', '2019-02-06', '2019-02-05', '2019-02-05', '2019-02-02', '2019-02-02', '2019-01-29', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-23', '2019-01-16', '2019-01-16', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-10', '2019-01-10', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-01']
list2 =['Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Segmenatation', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Heap  Failure', 'Heap  Failure', 'Type Error', 'I/O Error', 'Type Error', 'Type2 Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Heap  Failure', 'Type2 Error', 'Heap I/O', 'CPU  Recovery Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'CPU  Recovery Error', 'CPU  Recovery Error', 'Heap I/O', 'Type2 Error', 'Heap  Failure', 'I/O Error', 'Heap I/O', 'Type Error', 'Type2 Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error']
```

From this I need to plot graphs in the link provided below https://plot.ly/javascript/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart

I tried to use the default dict and get single key multiple values, but the json in the link is pretty different.I was scripting in Python

Please help me.

Tried this, but got no result

```
from collections import defaultdict
v = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(list1)):
  v[list1[i]].append(list2[i])
```

Comment: Zip the lists together: `v = dict(zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: @zwer It doesn't works because I have only 24 unique dates in list1 and total count is 33. Since a dict cannot have duplicate keys, the above function doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stacked bar charts Plotly expects each data type in a separate trace. In your case you would need to create a bar chart for each error type (assuming you want the dates on the x-axis and the y-axis is the count of errors).

For small lists you can just loop over them and search for matches. For larger datasets Pandas (or something similar) should be more performant and easier to use.

```
import collections
import plotly

list1 = ['2019-03-05', '2019-02-20', '2019-02-20', '2019-02-19', '2019-02-18', '2019-02-16', '2019-02-13', '2019-02-12', '2019-02-12', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-08', '2019-02-07', '2019-02-06', '2019-02-05', '2019-02-05', '2019-02-02', '2019-02-02', '2019-01-29', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-23', '2019-01-16', '2019-01-16', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-10', '2019-01-10', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-01']
list2 =['Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Segmenatation', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Heap  Failure', 'Heap  Failure', 'Type Error', 'I/O Error', 'Type Error', 'Type2 Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'Heap  Failure', 'Type2 Error', 'Heap I/O', 'CPU  Recovery Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error', 'CPU  Recovery Error', 'CPU  Recovery Error', 'Heap I/O', 'Type2 Error', 'Heap  Failure', 'I/O Error', 'Heap I/O', 'Type Error', 'Type2 Error', 'Type Error', 'Type Error']

assert len(list1) == len(list2)

traces = []

# get a set of unique errors
for error in sorted(list(set(list2))):
    errors = collections.defaultdict(int)

    # check this particular error occurred on this date
    for ix, d in enumerate(list1):
        if list2[ix] == error:
            errors[d] += 1

    traces.append(plotly.graph_objs.Bar(x=list(errors.keys()),
                                        y=list(errors.values()),
                                        name=error))

layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(
    barmode='stack'
)
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)

plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @maximilian . This worked like a pro. Kudos :)